# Use grep to erase a particular element in a multidimensional array in perl

Tags: perl

I would like to erase a particular element stored by a multidimensional array in perl knowing the exact position of the element;

For example, I have the following array:

```
$a[1][0]=43
$a[1][1]=2
$a[1][2]=3
$a[1][3]=34
$a[1][4]=52
```

I would like to erase the element equal to "34" ($a[1][3]) and obtain in the end something like

```
$a[1][0]=43
$a[1][1]=2
$a[1][2]=3
$a[1][3]=52
```

My actual dataset is bigger and I know only the first array reference (e.g. $a[ "this one" ][" uknown "]) and the value (the "34"); for an unidimensional array I would use the `grep` function as:

```
@a = grep {$_ != $element_to_erase} @a;
```

but with a multidimensional array I don't know how to. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to grep through the second dimension on a specific row (ie. the index of the first dimension is fixed):

```
$a[$row] = [ grep { $_ != 34 } @{ $a[ $row ] } ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the first dimension:

```
foreach my $element ( @a ) {

    $element = [ grep { $_ != 34 } @$element ];
}
```

Which could be re-written with a `map`:

```
@a = map [ grep { $_ != 34 } @$_ ], @a;
```

Comment: sorry, maybe I was not clear. The value of the array, let s say the "34", can appear elsewhere. That's why I specified the fact that I know the first array reference (in this case "1") because for each different array, if it exists, I am sure it is unique. Both solution I think would erase all the "34" they would find

Comment: And if you knew you only need to process a specific row of `@a`, you could just do `$a[$row] = [ grep { $_ != 34 } @{$a[$row]} ]`.